# Interaction between two Clouds

Tags: cloud, uec

I have setup the Cloud-A with 1 - [CLC+CC] and 2 - [NC] computers. I have another Cloud-B with same configuration using the Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud

Both of them working fine individually, in the same LAN.

Now if I want to add the NC of Cloud-A to CC of Cloud-B, [in case the resources of Cloud-B are exhausted] how can I make it possible ? I guess this calls for the interoperability stuff...

Could you please explain what happens exactly when we ask for instance, the direct interaction happens between the client and NC or it goes through the CLC and CC ?

What I want to say is, say there are multiple cloud providers. A user is subscribed to any one of them, say Cloud-A for IaaS. As the requirements are dynamic, all the resources of Cloud-A may get exhausted. There may be another Cloud-B which can provide the services but that Cloud-A can't ask the client to go for Cloud-B.

So if it is possible to have some co-ordination between this two providers to share resources mutually, making client fully unaware of whats going on in the background....?

Comment: Can you make clear how this is related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu server comes with stuff to create cloud infrastructure

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks all for replying.. 
@ Scaine : I mentioned that I am using the UBUNTU enterprise cloud and I got this problem while having two clouds..  :)
@ Bubblegun : yup sure.. but this does not address the issue I raised.. please let me know if you have any idea.. :)
@ codeMonk : I guess this is better than ServerFault, as am getting comments no matter what they are.. ;)

Comment: I think you might want to rephrase your question here. What I see when I read your question, I have cloud A, and cloud B working individually. I want to use resources on cloud B, when the resources in cloud A are depleted, or unavailable.

When I get asked questions like that, I would say, allocate the resources you need to accommodate what you wish to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible but you would need to post your exact NIC configuration to make it easier.

Is there a good reason to have two clouds here? If you went down to one cloud the issue would solve itself.